# Looking for foot pressure database collected from pressure sensors

Tags: data-request, medical, uses-of-open-data, wikidata

I am working on a project where I need foot pressure data that a person put on his foot while walking, running, or doing any other practice. I searched a lot in the search engines and I couldn't find anything. The data could be collected from pressure sensors or pressure mats.
I would be grateful if any of you know of such a database and can share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be coming a little bit late, but hopefully it can help someone in the future. SFootDB is the largest publicly available gait database, CASIA-D is also a great underfoot pressure database, and there is a database available from UoM that also has underfoot pressure.
Cheers